# Accessing a SSH shell session between Rpi and computer from another computer

Tags: raspbian, ssh, terminal

I have a SSH session between computer A(Linux) and RaspberryPi(Raspbian). It is carrying out a build process. I need to access that session to see the console outputs and continue using it. I know that SSHing will create a new session.

Is there a way to use the same session from computer B(Linux) in same network?

Comment: Why can't you continue to use the session you build in? What is it you are building? What build system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not so much use now, but if in future you are doing something similar, use GNU Screen (http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or TMUX (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and start the ssh session from there. You can then detach and re-attach the session from your screen as and when required. This means that even when you're not attached to the session, it's still working in the background.